# Decoherence, "nonobservability of superpositions" and measurements on qubits

Tags: measurements, density-operator, superposition, decoherence

**Observation:**

Due to decoherence, the reduced density matrix of a system that has interacted with an environment might look like this:

$$a_0a_0^*|0\rangle\langle 0|+a_1a_1^*|1\rangle\langle 1|+$$

$$a_0a_1^*|0\rangle\langle  1|r+a_0^*a_1|1\rangle\langle 0| r^*$$

One usually says to this, that "no quantum properties" or "no superposition effects of $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$ are observable", if r=0.

**Confusion:**

What confuses me is the following: Given $r=0$. So one looks at a mixed state of the form $$q_1|0\rangle\langle 0|+q_2|1\rangle\langle 1|.\tag{1}$$
Only in the case of $q_1=1/2$ there is total randomness, so to speak measurement probabilities equals $1/2$, when considering any measurement basis (in the abstract sense one does when looking at qubits or spin1/2 particles). Otherwise, usually measurement probabilities aren't $1/2$. Doesn't that mean (relative to a certain basis) there still are superposition effects observable (through measurements in the abstract sense as I will elaborate further in a second)? Doesn't that mean that the state *has* still some quantum properties?

As far as I can tell, with $q_1\neq1/2$ measurement probabilities are only $1/2$ in the following two measurements: 1) A measurement of $O=|0\rangle\langle 0|-|1\rangle\langle 1|$. A measurement that (besides a second orthogonal one) asks for the state $|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle+|1\rangle\right)$ - observable $O=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|-|\psi^{\perp}\rangle\langle\psi^{\perp}|$.

This can be seen as the state (1) can be looked at in the bloch-sphere as a arrow with certain length. This length is $0$ if $q_1=1/2$. A measurement results in this arrow to flip towards one of two antiparralel arrows with length 1. The relative orientation to those antiparallel arrows gives the measurement propabilities, the length of the state vector amplifies the influence of the relative orientation.

Comment: *Doesn't that mean that the state has still some quantum properties?* It definitely remains a quantum state... but not a pure one.

Comment: @RogerVadim, no, if q1 = 1 - q2 is chosen as 0 or 1 then it is a pure state.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent $\rho^2=\rho$?

Comment: It has been a while since I last did this, but IIRC after the diagonalisation of the density operator, any superposition measurement thereof will obtain strictly less extreme probabilities, with results in agreement with classical mixtures. There cannot be any weirdness like the spin x states, which give half-half probabilities in the spin z measurements, yet giving non-half-half probabilities if you measure in any direction that has a bit of x component.

Comment: @RogerVadim in those two specific cases that correspond to pure states, yes, they do satisfy that.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I think this deviates too far from the subject. Anyhow, my original comment was pointing out a rather mundane matter - the state by no means become *classical*, just because the decoherence happened.

Comment: Does a weak measurement process leave us with some remaining quantum properties? Yes. Is that what this is trying to describe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoherence is always basis specific. After complete decoherence in a certain basis ($r=0$), one will not be able to observe coherences *in that basis*, but other coherence and therefore superposition properties may still be observed.

For the case considered here, complete decoherence in the $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}$ basis means that the expectation value of $|0\rangle\langle 1|$ is zero. As a result, the overlap of the state that has been completely decohered (here $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$) with any state of the form $\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$ will be the same as the overlap of the state with a probabilistic mixture of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ with probabilities $|\alpha|^2$ and $|\beta|^2$; the relative phase between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ becomes irrelevant.  But there is still coherence in the $\{|0\rangle+|1\rangle,|0\rangle-|1\rangle\}$ basis: the expectation value of $(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)(\langle 0|-\langle 1|)$ is nonzero and overlaps with states of the form $\alpha(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)+\beta(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)$ will certainly depend on the relative phase between $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

In the Bloch sphere picture, the basis with respect to which decoherence occurs is represented by a particular axis. Decoherence is the shrinking of the Bloch vector toward that axis. In the case here, decoherence retains the Bloch vector's height and brings it closer to the $z$ axis; complete decoherence ($r=0$) projects the Bloch vector onto the $z$ axis. If the state began on the equator, it would become maximally mixed, while if it began at the top or bottom of the sphere it would remain unchanged. No matter what axis is chosen, the Bloch vector can only shrink, so this is the general sense in which a state can only become "more mixed" or "more classical" via decoherence.

Now, if you actually want to discuss why people connect decoherence to classicality,  you typically have to go beyond qubits. The idea is that certain quantum states most closely resemble the world we classically see around us, and that this is the basis to which decoherence forces states. For the qubit example, this would be the case if somehow we were happy to call $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ classical while calling $|0\rangle\pm|1\rangle$ quantum, which would not be well motivated at all. But you can use this example for understanding the mathematics and intuition of how decoherence operates, then imagine what would happen if you had many more dimensions, more complicated systems, and some way of choosing a basis in which the states look similar to our classical world.

Comment: In the second paragraph (second row). With "the state" in "the overlap of the state with" - do you mean $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$?

Comment: You said there are coherences in the $\{|0\rangle+|1\rangle,|0\rangle-|1\rangle\}$ basis. Which is a measurement in the $|\psi\rangle,|\psi^{\perp}\rangle$ basis as I called it. Are you sure there are no coherences for $|\alpha|^2|0\rangle\langle 0|+|\beta|^2|1\rangle\langle 1|$ when measured in this basis? I found the probabilities (as stated in the question) to be 1/2, regarless of $|\alpha|^2$.

Comment: @manuel459 I edited to answer your first question. As for the second, I said there *are* coherences in the $|\pm\rangle=(|0\rangle\pm|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ basis: we can write things like $|0\rangle=(|+\rangle+|-\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. The existence of coherences is not at odds with all of those probabilities being the same. Coherences mean that overlaps of your state with states of the form $\alpha|+\rangle+\beta|-\rangle$ depend on the relative phase between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (equivalently, that writing your state in the $|\pm\rangle$ basis will yield something with off-diagonal components).

Comment: I understand. So just to clarify for me. If one says that after decoherence "there are no quantum properties observable" (observable relating to everyday world observations of superpositions of position states e.g.), what does this associate to in the qubit picture? I guess in other words: How to properly distinguish $p_1|\psi_1\rangle+p_2|\psi_2\rangle$ and $p_1^2|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|+p_2^2|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2|$ if $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ are orthogonal?

Comment: Trying to answer my question before: One could use measurements in the basis $|\psi\rangle=p_1|\psi_1\rangle+p_2|\psi_2\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle^{\perp}$ because in the pure state case, one would get 1 outcome with propbabiliy 1 (this differs from the mixed state).  That's the formal analogon of finding interference patterns e.g. in the double slit.If that probability is not 1, you get no interferences.

Comment: Actually let me file a new question for this. I will link it here rightafter so you can answer it there if you want to. Thank you.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/760251/decoherence-nonobservability-of-superpositions-and-its-analogy-in-a-model-us

Comment: @manuel459 you got it - any measurement basis other than that of $|\psi_1\rangle$, $|\psi_2\rangle$ should give you *some* interference properties. The $|\psi\rangle$, $|\psi\rangle^\top$ basis might give you *maximal* interference properties (in the sense that if something oscillates with the relative phase between $p_1$ and $p_2$ then the oscillation will have maximal amplitude).

Comment: Couldn't one also look at the following measurement as the formal analogon to the observation "there are no quantum properties observable?": Namely measuring in the basis $|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle$ (which in general differs to the $|\psi\rangle,|\psi^{\perp}\rangle$ basis. As stated above a mixed state $p_1|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|+p_2|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2|$ would always show the behaviour of measurement results having probability $1/2$, while for pure states of the form $|\psi_1\rangle+|\psi_2\rangle$ this isn't the case.

Comment: I know from your comment regarding "probabilities being equal is not at odds..." but it should be at odds with them being not the same for a pure state, shouldn't they? I mean, the probabilities being not the same does indicate that there are some interferences in the $\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle$ basis? Sorry to bother you!

Comment: Now that I've thought about it, the analogy to whether one observes interference patterns or not should be seen in "all measurements and their results" (meaning not only 1 measurement, but just any measurement asking for a superposition state of some sort).